# Pandas mean of the same elements

Tags: database, pandas, dataframe, mean, rolling-computation

I am working with pandas and I have a list between 1949 and 1960, with months (January to December), and associated to each month a number (of people). Months are in column A, nb of people in column B.
I would like to calculate the mean of people for every month and determine the month with the maximum of people, over the time-period.

How can I do that ? I had the idea of using a rolling mean but I wanted to make sure there is a simpler way to do it before jumping into it too much.

It is organized as:

```
nf = 
A     B

Jan   3
Feb   5
...  ...
Jan   4
Feb   1
...  ...
Jan   0
Feb   9
...  ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

u can achieve this task useing `groupby()` method:

```
nf.groupby(['A'],as_index=false).mean()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
df = nf.groupby('A').mean()
```

This will give you the mean for each month.
Then you can sort the results:

```
df.sort_values(by=['B'], ascending = False)
```